# Need direction on a seemingly complex menu walker for automatically inserting a parent link li in it's submenu ul

Tags: menus, walker

I'd appreciate some direction on how to accomplish something with my WordPress menu. I've Googled this for hours without avail. I was to automatically insert a parent link into it's immediate submenu ul. For example, normal output is this:

Parent Menu Item 1
Parent Menu Item 2
--Submenu Item 1
--Submenu Item 2
Parent Menu Item 3

I'm looking for this:

Parent Menu Item 1
Parent Menu Item 2
--Parent Menu Item 2
--Submenu Item 1
--Submenu Item 2
Parent Menu Item 3

Again, any help and/or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the WordPress menu system in the admin interface, then you could simply add the Parent Menu Item 2 to the menu again and place it as a child element under the parent version of it. I don't see any need to even extend the WordPress Walker_Nav_Menu.